# Autodesk Forge - problem of viewing big files as a gltf model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, gltf

I have been trying to view gltf model with a 1 GB size, but the only small part of the model can be loaded. Is there any way to load all part of the model properly and to speed up the loading process?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the SVF2 [option here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready).